# Are there any alternatives to safe_mode in PHP 5.4?

Tags: php, security, safe-mode

PHP 5.4 finally removed [safe_mode](http://php.net/safe_mode) and [magic quotes](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php).

Are there any alternatives to them? To enhance the security level?

Comment: to what degree do you need to enhance security? is this for a hosting company or private/dedicated servers?

Comment: I meant that are there other ways similar to safe_mode but give better securing with less problems ?

Comment: Better applications make it more secure. `safe_mode` doesn't help you, but make everything more complex. There are good reasons, why they get cancelled.

Comment: What parts of safe mode do you want to emulate exactly? You'll need to give some detail for people to make some suggestions

Comment: Why don't you accept answers.

Answer (score 4):

I think the point of removing these features is that the PHP development team acknowledges that implementing security features/mechanisms in the application stack is not a panacea for securing Web applications.

There **shouldn't be direct code/configuration substitutes for these features in PHP**.  Instead:

- application developers should be more explicit about such things as reading in values from requests and the environment AND validating and escaping values, instead of letting features like `register_globals` and `magic_quotes` do so indiscriminantly.
- system engineers and system developers should consider permissions for all filesystem resources required by an application rather than having `safe_mode` limit the accessiblity and efficacy of built-in functions.

I'm sure someone will try to figure out how to re-create these features, and there will be a lot of late adopters that choose to stay on earlier versions of PHP instead of addressing security directly.  But if you really are concerned about security, **don't look for shortcuts**.